# Hypothesis Testing Using Tail Probability – Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, negative-binomial-distribution

I am comparing **count** data in treatment versus control.

The question suggests that the count data follows a negative binomial distribution with mean and variance estimated from the controls.

**To compare if `Treatment::count` is significantly lower or higher compared to `Control::count`** :

The question wants me to calculate the tail probability that the null NB distribution generates a `NULL::count` that is more extreme than `Treatment::count`.
[image]

Where

- i = Scenario
- u = #Count in *ith* Scenario
- A = Control
- B = Treatment
- x = #Count from a negative binomial distribution; parameter defined by control *A*.

I have only done hypothesis testing using normal distribution and binomial distribution, and I'm not quite too sure how I should proceed.

Let's say for scenario (i = 1):

The control group *A* defines a `~NB(mean = 14, var = 72)`.

And the treatment group *B* has a mean count of `10`.

1. How do I calculate the tail probability in this case?
2. How about if the mean count for treatment group *B* is `15`? In which case it's higher than the mean for control *A* `14`?

---

More Details:

The data I'm working with is from a CRISPR screen.

The count represents the number of `gRNA` counted in each sample.

There are 90230 `gRNAs` in total, and the pipeline I'm following suggests that *EACH* `gRNA count` follows a negative binomial distribution with parameters defined from the control group.

I want to know if the `gRNA count` of each of the 90230 `gRNAs` in the treatment group is significantly higher / lower than the control.

Comment: There are several versions of the "negative binomial" distribution, please specify the PDF or say specifically what is being counted.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks so much for the guidance - I've updated the post with some details. Because I have a limited background in stats, I'm not sure if I'm still missing some relevant information. Please let me know!